# Severe Lagging on Wine and PlayOnLinux with openSUSE

Tags: opensuse, performance, wine

I am having an issue with the performance of some older games. For example if I am trying to run Panzer General Forever or Panzer General 3D, I am facing extreme lagging on clicks and when moving the mouse. On Windows this has worked fine before.

In my attempts I have tried to use both, PlayOnLinux and Wine in its 32 and 64bit versions. In addition I have tried using different Windows Versions to no avail.

I was wondering if anyone has faced the same issues or has an idea of what I can try.

I am on openSUSE Leap 42.1, fully updated and using lates Wine and POL versions.

Thanks and Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like, it is just Wine.

I have tried on two more machines, running openSUSE 42.1. One is a Desktop and another Laptop and the issue is the same. Digging through the forums and posts found through Google has shown similar information.

So, for now: not much hope but wait if a future Wine version will fix this.

Cheers,

Ben